# Can you customize the current location marker in react native maps?

Tags: google-maps, mapkit, react-native-maps

I'd like to use a custom marker image instead of the pulsing blue dot - is there a way to customize this in react native maps using apple maps for ios and google maps for Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot change the default current location dot. A work around is to pass the user's location into a `<Marker />` with your custom image and turn off `showsUserLocation` to hide the default blue dot. Here are the [Marker docs](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md).

Then you can track the user's location using [Geolocation.watchPosition](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html). If you set the user's location to state it will trigger a rerender when the user moves.

Comment: cool, but that won't keep updating as the user moves unless I update it myself continuously correct?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey you can track the user's location using Geolocation.watchPosition.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

If you set the user's location to state it will trigger a rerender when the user moves.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom marker and hook up an event listener to track the user and update the location of the marker as your user moves.

This event listener is available within the framework.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#watchposition

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what the others have said, <strike>you can use the `MapView`'s `onUserLocationChange` event directly without installing a dependency like `@react-native-community/geolocation`</strike>. This only works if `showsUserLocation` is set to `true`.

If you are using Expo, you can use `expo-location`'s API to get the last user location.